# Dynamic Reverse Proxy with Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to implement a dynamic reverse proxy with Nginx 1.25.3. My desired flow should be:

1. from my web browser (e.g. Chrome) I pass the following URL. http://localhost/?redirect_url=http://example.com
2. Nginx (that I run locally with a Dockerfile) receives the request and extracts http://example.com
3. Nginx proxy_pass URL link http://example.com
4. The web browser receive the HTML page of http://google.com from Nginx

I used the following nginx.conf file:

```
map $arg_redirect_url $dynamic_redirect_url {
    default "";
    "~^(?P<url>.+)$" $url;
}
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        # Proxy pass to the dynamically determined URL
        proxy_pass $dynamic_redirect_url;


        # Other proxy settings can be added as needed
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        
        # Additional headers for better compatibility
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    }
}
```

When I try to pass into my browser the link "http://localhost/?redirect_url=http://example.com" I got the following error: "502 Bad gateway".

Please, consider that if I substitute (into nginx.conf file) the dynamically extracted url command ("proxy_pass $dynamic_redirect_url;") with a static proxy_pass ("proxy_pass https://google.com") it works well.

Please, also note that the map directive are working well because if I put this command into nginx.conf file: return 200 {"message": "Hello, this: $dynamic_redirect_url"};
it extracts the right URL (that is http://example.com)

thanks in advance for your helping

Comment: Is there anything in the nginx error log?

Comment: Probably I found the problema (not the solution). The HTML page that I trying to download has other resources to download (e.g. css, js, ico); but it try to download the resources from localhost and not from Nginx.